# VS Code Syntax Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I'm making VS Code extension for a new language (*My own language*).

I know about `snippets` in VS Code extensions, but if you work with Python (I only paid attention to Python extensions) you may see some keywords like `for` has both snippet and keyword autocomplete (keywords like `from` and `import`).

My Question is how to add this feature to my extension?[image: example]

Comment: write a completion provider

Comment: Microsoft Python extension has a language server for that.